# Problema con un programa para resolver un problema con la teoría de números

Tags: c++, matemáticas

Problema

Se tienen 2 números de un digito cada uno, el tercer numero se forma de la suma de los 2 números anteriores, tomando de el, solo la posición del digito, y así sucesivamente hasta que el ciclo regresa a los 2 numeros originales.

Entrada

Dos números enteros de un solo dígito, en líneas separadas.

Salida

En la primera línea tu programa deberá escribir la serie completa separada por espacios. En la segunda línea tu programa deberá imprimir el número de pasos para regresar a los números iniciales.

Ejemplo

```
Entrada 
1 8
Salida
1 8 9 7 6 3 9 2 1 3 4 7 1 8
12
```

Sólo he logrado que imprima hasta: `1 8 9 7 6 3 9 2 1`.

Creo que es porque `1` termina siendo `x` y al ser igual a `a` se rompe el ciclo pero el problema dice: "y así sucesivamente hasta que el ciclo regresa a los 2 numero originales.", pero no lo he conseguido.

Aquí mi código en c++:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
   int main(){
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);
    int a,b,c,i=0,k=0;
    cin>>a>>b;
    int x=a,y=b;
    cout<<x<<" "<<y<<" ";
    do{
        c=x+y;
        k=c%10;
        x=y;
        y=k;
        cout<<k<<" ";
        i++;
    }while(x!=a&&y!=b);
    cout<<endl<<i;
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El programa no funciona correctamente porque la condición del while es incorrecta.

El bucle se debe repetir hasta que 'x' sea igual a 'a' e 'y' sea igual a 'b'. Por tanto, en el while hay que poner la condición contraria: mientras 'x' no sea igual a 'a' Ó 'y' no sea igual a 'b':

```
while(x!=a || y!=b);
```